# Combine 2 sparse QR factorizations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have sparse matrix $A_1$ which is size $m_1 \times n$ and another sparse matrix $A_2$ which is size $m_2 \times n$, where $m_1 < n$ and $m_2 \leq n$ and plan on stacking them to make a sparse matrix $A$:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}A_1 \\ A_2\end{bmatrix}$

If I have the $QR$ factorization of $A_1$ (say, $Q_1R_1$) and the $QR$ factorization of $A_2$ (say, $Q_2R_2$), is there any way to combine these factors, $Q_1,R_1,Q_2,R_2$ into the $QR$ factorization of the entire $A$ matrix?

If it is not possible to find the combined $Q$ matrix, is it at least possible to do so for the combined $R$ matrix? Again, just to be clear, the matrix $A$ can be either tall and skinny or wide and fat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}A_1\\A_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}Q_1R_1 \\ Q_2R_2\end{bmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}Q_1 & 0 \\ 0 & Q_2\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{orthogonal matrix}}\begin{bmatrix}R_1\\R_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
To get a QR factorization of $A$, you need to compute the QR factorization of the "stacked" matrix $[R_1^T,R_2^T]^T$:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}Q_1 & 0 \\ 0 & Q_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}R_1\\R_2\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}Q_1 & 0 \\ 0 & Q_2\end{bmatrix}\tilde{Q} R=QR.
$$
Note that you don't need to compute the matrix $Q$ explicitly but you can keep it in the factorized form:
$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}Q_1 & 0 \\ 0 & Q_2\end{bmatrix}\tilde{Q},
$$
which is sufficient to compute, e.g., matrix-vector products with $Q$. This is a well-known way how to compute parallel QR factorizations of "tall and skinny" matrices, so it's usually called the "tall and skinny QR factorization".

Comment: Is there no way to take into account that R1 and R2 are already QR factors, aside from refactoring them once they are stacked? 

Is it even beneficial then to have the QR factors of A1 and A2, rather then just computing one decomposition on the combined matrix A?

Comment: Also, is there a similar strategy when horizontally stacking A1 and A2, e.g. A = [A1 A2]?

Comment: @user92817 "Is there no way to take into account that R1 and R2 are already QR factors, aside from refactoring them once they are stacked?" None I know about. Note that it's not refactoring, it's a sort of recursive factorisation. It's efficient, e.g., for parallel implementation. "Is it even beneficial then to have the QR factors of A1 and A2, rather then just computing one decomposition on the combined matrix A?" If you don't need QR of $A_1$ and $A_2$ and can compute that of the stacked matrix, then certainly you can do that directly.

Comment: @user92817 "Also, is there a similar strategy when horizontally stacking A1 and A2, e.g. A = [A1 A2]?" Nope, unless you would be fine with the LQ decomposition instead.